# Why does MyLocationOverlay not work?

Tags: android, google-maps

in my app I would like to see the little blue dot that follows you as you walk around in google maps. Below is the code, however I do not see a blue dot anywhere, even when I export the app to my phone!

```
public class UCLAProjectActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        int maxLat = (int) (34.07687 * 1E6);
        int maxLon = (int) (-118.438239 * 1E6);
        int minLat = (int) (34.06489 * 1E6);
        int minLon = (int) (-118.452358 * 1E6);
         List <Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            // "this" refers to your activity
            MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
            myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
            overlays.add(myLocationOverlay);

        mc.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon));

        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your manifest.